# Is it possible to remove a national park in civ VI?

Tags: civilization-6

Although it provides a good amount of tourism and score era, after sometimes I just want those tile back to do some other stuffs. Is it possible ? The only thing I can do so far is growing trees within that national park tile with builders. Any other action seem to be undoable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to remove a national park once established.

Source: [civfanatics forum](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/remove-national-parks.605768/)